# A word for a collection of collections of video content?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, phrase-requests

If I were to put together collections of scientific lectures either by speaker or topic, what might I call them as a whole, if all the collections too were grouped into one item?

I am looking for a word that is similar to *anthology*, but that seems to refer exclusively  to literary content. I have thought about *series*, but what if you have a collection of series (like, what would all the series of Star Trek be called if they were put into one set)? Simply, I have considered *collection* and *selection*, and more aptly, *compilation*. *Collection* might work but it seems to general of a word and *compilation* seems accurate, but kind of sounds like tech jargon. A single word would be nice, but I am open to a two or three word combo. As it sits now, I feel stuck with *[unique name] collection series*.

Comment: "Star Trek: The Boxset", "Star Trek: Every Trek".... Be careful though, in the UK they use series for what Americans call a season.

Comment: @Elliot That is good to know. Though I am American, this product will be sold and marketed to both. However, there is no recurring element to the content. The lectures were given at conferences that are not necessarily associated with each other. So maybe series is not really a good word at all.

Comment: But as time goes, I will be making more collections so maybe series is good, because they will be recurring every other year or so.

Comment: Perhaps then "lecture series".

Comment: Have you considered the term *compendium*?

Comment: I used to put my stuff in folders and name them accordingly. Still took a lot of effort to search through them. Now, I just search by modification date/name/file type/part of the name(most useful) and find everything much faster. Why bother?

Answer (score 3):

If it were me, I would prefer [whatever] *Library*.

The [something] *Collection* works great though. See for example [The Criterion Collection](http://www.criterion.com/).

Comment: Film library is a very common term in the movie industry. A library may be a collection with one theme (e.g., by actor, director, time period), multiple collections with their own unrelated themes, or just a random collection for the sake of being collected.

Comment: I have used the word Library before and did consider it for this, but I think it implies entirety. It might work with a slight rebranding in some other areas.

Comment: For my part, I consider a library to be a work in progress. For example, on my computer I have a music library, which I'm constantly updating - just as a public library is always making aquisitions.

Answer (score -1):

Video and literary collections often use **Complete Series** to indicate that the collection comprises all works related to the title, rather than a single season or subseries. Literary and musical collections often use **Complete Works** to indicate the same thing.

Comment: I'm still trying to refine my question. The Star Trek series example I gave is close, but all the various compilations are only related by scientific field, so seeing them side-by-side does not necessarily imply that they are part of the same thing.

Comment: It's the _complete_ that indicates that the collection is comprehensive rather than limited to a particular series of lectures or point in time.

Comment: I think *complete* is not appropriate, given fredsbend's recent comments, since he plans to continue to add more content.

Comment: Good point. You could infer “complete up to this point,” but usually **Complete X** is used for retrospective collections of series/works that aren't expected to get new entries.